# Notebook suddenly shut down when not using two monitors

Tags: boot, multiple-monitors, shutdown

I used to run a 14.02.2 LTS installation, and then I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04. That's were a strange problem started: I use my computer with a second monitor, and when I upgraded it, the monitor was plugged in and transmitting.

After the upgrade, if I try to switch my notebook on without an external monitor, the system boots up to the login screen and then suddenly shut down. Sometimes the screen just go black, as if it is hibernating, and sometimes it really turn itself off and need to be booted from scratch. This last scenario is happening more often lately. I then need to connect an external monitor, complete boot and turn the external monitor off by using xrandr.

My computer is an old Semp Toshiba IS 1422, 3.7 GB of RAM, Intel CPU P6200 and Intel Iron Lake Mobile as a graphic card.

Thanks in advance by any help, and if you require additional info please let me know.